# pyodbc throws exception alternate times while connecting databases

Tags: python, pandas, teradata, pyodbc, vertica

I have tried to create a cross-db validation script using pyodbc as login driver for both Vertica and Teradata databases .Everything runs fine if I run query for one-database login i.e. either vertica or Teradata . Problem starts when I run scripts in both Vertica and Teradata . **Every alternate times the Driver throws below error**.

```
(<class 'pyodbc.Error'>, Error('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!'), <traceback object at 0x10c18f4d0>)
```

Below is the connection string of vertica :

```
def create_connection_nwk():
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=Vertica;SERVER=vertica-server;DATABASE=VERTICA-DATABASE;PORT=5433;UID=username;PWD=passphrase")
    return conn
```

Below is the connection string of Teradata :

```
def create_connection_redwood():
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=Teradata;DBCNAME=mydatabase;UID=username;PWD=passphrase;QUIETMODE=YES", autocommit=True,unicode_results=True)
    return conn
```

And I use the connections as below , reading queries from two files source and target.

```
def dqm_newark() :
    conn_nwk = create_connection_nwk()
    dataframes_newark = []
    tgtfile = open('tgtqueries.sql', 'rU').read()
    querylist = tgtfile.split(';')
    querylist.pop()
    for query in querylist :
        dataframes_newark.append(pd.read_sql(query, conn_nwk))
    close_connection(conn_nwk)
    return dataframes_newark,querylist


def dqm_redwood() :
    conn_rw = create_connection_redwood()
    dataframes_redwood = []
    srcfile = open('srcqueries.sql', 'rU').read()
    querylist = srcfile.split(';')
    querylist.pop()
    for query in querylist :
        dataframes_redwood.append(pd.read_sql(query, conn_rw))
    close_connection(conn_rw)
    return dataframes_redwood,querylist
```

and I match resultsets using pandas dataframe :

```
assert_frame_equal(src_dataframes[i], tgt_dataframes[i],check_names=False)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "DQM.py", line 158, in <module> compare_data() File "DQM.py", line 94, in compare_data 
src_dataframes,querylist_redwood = dqm_redwood() File "DQM.py", line 31, in 
dqm_redwood conn_rw = create_connection_redwood() File "DQM.py", line 125, in 
create_connection_redwood conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=Teradata;DBCNAME=databasename;UID=username;PWD=passwrod;Q‌​UIETMODE=YES", autocommit=True,unicode_results=True) 
Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing the problem alternate times .Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: Are you using threads in program? Also, what is the threading value set to in your odbcinst.ini file?

Comment: No I am not aware of threads. I am not using it.

Comment: Could you check the odbcinst.ini file to see what the threading setting is or if it isn't there at all?

Comment: Also what is the version of pyodbc you have installed?

Comment: @woot : After your first comment I added `Threading     = 1` in odbcinst.ini file and odbc.ini file under **etc** folder. But no change has happened. And version is **pyodbc-3.0.10** .

Comment: Running out of ideas. Could you show the full traceback?

Comment: Teradata connection seems culprit as suggested by stacktrace.What am I missing in Teradata driver connection ?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DQM.py", line 158, in <module>
    compare_data()
  File "DQM.py", line 94, in compare_data
    src_dataframes,querylist_redwood = dqm_redwood()
  File "DQM.py", line 31, in dqm_redwood
    conn_rw = create_connection_redwood()
  File "DQM.py", line 125, in create_connection_redwood
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=Teradata;DBCNAME=databasename;UID=username;PWD=passwrod;QUIETMODE=YES", autocommit=True,unicode_results=True)
Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
`

Comment: From the pandas doc, `SQLAlchemy engine or DBAPI2 connection (fallback mode)
Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.`  Perhaps you need to change it to use SQLAlchemy?